# 'Release' shapes from CompoundPath

Tags: svg, paperjs

I have a complex shape that was generated using a `CompoundPath` with multiple `Path` children. This is an example shape:

[image]

I want to know if there's some method on `paperjs` or some other way to generate simple `Paths` with the different shapes generated from the combination of all the `Paths` in the `CompoundPath`, something like the `Release` operation `Adobe Illustrator` as stated [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/66258/fill-holes-in-compound-path-with-color).

I need this in order to be able to fill the different `Path` with colors using the `fillColor` property which is not possible when they are inside a `CompoundPath`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it as stated [here](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/1196). Quoting [@iconexperience](https://github.com/iconexperience):

> I think what you need to do is to call setClockwise(true) on your
>   CompoundPath and then call reorient(). This will set the orientation
>   (clockwise/counter-clockwise) of each child path so that if several
>   paths are stacked above each other, their orientation will be
>   alternating. starting with clockwise for the bottom path. After that,
>   if the orientation of a child in the CompoundPath is clockwise it
>   represents a 'hole' or white area in your image. a clockwise
>   orientation means that the path is filled.
>
> If you then clone the children of the CompoundPath and fill the ones
>   with clockwise orientation in brown color and the other ones in white
>   color, you should have a result that will look like the original.
>
> reorient() will only work if there are no intersections between the
>   paths. Also, please note that reorient() is only available in the
>   development version of Paper.js.

Answer (score 0):

`compoundPath.parent.addChildren(compoundPath.children)` would be similar operations with `Release` in paperjs.

I create [an example](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/fZLBisIwEIZfZSgsTUGrtuChsuzBF1jcY9tDTEcbTBNJo7KI777TtAfbdTeQQCb/909mknugeYNBFnyd0Ik6mAXCVN1+sQBhkTsEYZqzuejqk7u60FduwaJw8A4ab9AF4x3tuT4qZPlqOYN+9ksZ9YiQVihcPVNbH2J5Ssp0Wc5ggMdI8gpZ/4ukfyHrV8hTdcR1pcXtZe8sF44Nt46mkeRXJCW7Z6v4IJXaGmUsmYZ7xcUpLHShu7Yqo6ddHaFewKKY/HWr6AlY0nVzGQ0GO1TIW+zvLx02LeUYO9RSVRZ13CopyGqS4MzpzMW8qraDkHmbqc5iY64ePxjLfDbK5KWxQn109QbkfL6B6F5ooOGPclmOqpfwBgl8QGixCiGD8BuVMjdqx6PQ9OH29M1OZyO1a4MsLx8/).